# Birthday problem, but matching couples instead of individuals

Tags: probability, self-study, matching, birthday-paradox

Suppose *n* couples are invited to a party. What is the probability that there are at least
two husband–wife pairs such that the husbands have the same birthdays and so do their
wives?

Comment: If this is for some subject could you tag it as `self study` please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not much difference between the two. In case of individuals the probability of two people sharing birthdays is $1/365$. In case of couples it is $1/365^2$, that's all. You just replace this number and it will do. You can think about it in terms of each couple having a sort of joint birthday, a total of $365^2$ possibilities instead of $365$.

Comment: So simple, thanks! I was definitely overthinking it.